# Intersecting a polygon with a line

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, intersect

I'm having an issue intersecting a polygon with a line in QGIS. The split with lines option has worked for me so far but for some reason wont work for this polygon on the left. I need the polygon top be split by the yellow line going through it. Does anyone have any ideas why it works for the others but not the one on the left?

[image]

Comment: Is the line continuous, or split? Does the polygon have geometry issues? Have you checked its geometry?

Comment: I had to add an extra bit onto the line to make sure it completely intersected the polygon. The polygon was made at the same time as the other polygons using the same data layer so I figured it must be ok. I am very new to QGIS so I don't actually know much about checking geometry. I just had a look under the vector tab and clicked check validity and then tried to run intersect with line again but it still hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Did you try to buffer the polygon with a very small distance? If it still doesn't work: can you provide your data for testing?